# How to extract all items from a list based on one match

Tags: index-match

I would like to retrieve multiple results for index match. I have an example sheet where columns A and B are my raw data, ColE is A but sorted in alphabetical order and ColG is the desired outcome. I'd be most grateful if someone could help me find the right formula in ColF to obtain the same outcome as ColG. Many thanks!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Vr-Fu0VBG79RPQ58VAXE4bYfSGvM6xdze1Hx9UXW78/edit#gid=0